# How to export selected columns in ui-grid angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using UI grid export functionality to export grid columns in csv format.I want to let users to select columns for export. My question is How can I make selection on columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, There is no suitable way to export selected columns. By the way, I changed the **uiGridExporterConstants** to '**VISIBLE**' and I changed the visibility of the columns before sending the grid to the export service.
This works for me.